# About data intensive and form intensive web applications

Tags: java, web-development, application-design, jee

Can someone please highlight the definition and differences between data intensive and form intensive web applications.It would be really helpful if suitable java based web application framework or technology stack that is suitable for each kinf of architecture is highlighted.

I just was doing research on feasibility of angularjs with java web application.I was reading through this link blog.angular-university.io/… where it implies that angular is suitable for form intensive web apps.  Whereas in this link springtutorials.com/start-here it is mentioned that angular front end with spring is not suited for data intensive apps.  Since I am relatively new to web app development I needed clear difference between two

Comment: Do you have any references for these definitions? If there was something specific about each one that you didn't understand, you'd get a lot more help. Otherwise, it's just letting someone else search the web for you and just repeat the definitions.

Comment: @JeffO thanks for your time.I just was doing research on feasibility of angularjs with java web application.I was reading through this link blog.angular-university.io/… where it implies that angular is suitable for form intensive web apps.Wheras in this link springtutorials.com/start-here it is mentioned that angular front end with spring is not suited for data intensive apps.Since I am relatively new to web app development I needed clear difference between two

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add that info. Not everyone reads comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is a client-centric technology.  Data is sent to an Angular application from the server, and most of the UI rendering takes place in the web browser.  High user interactivity is promoted, because most of the UI development work takes place in Javascript, in the browser.

Spring is a server-centric technology.  The bulk of the page rendering is done server side.  Data is not sent to the browser directly; rather, the data is pushed into  html templates (more or less), and the resulting pages are pushed out to the browser essentially completed.  It's possible to render an entire Spring application without ever touching Javascript, though you can still use Javascript for things like client-side validation and dynamic addition of controls.

The phrases "data intensive" and "form intensive" are kind of misnomers, as any given application is essentially going to use the same amount of data whether it is created in Angular or Spring.  The difference lies in the way that the form is generated and the degree of interactivity that it offers.

Comment: thanks for the reply.Assume that I am developing a page for one of banking application which has lot of fields and on submission lot of cpu intensive processing is done before giving out response.Lets say server side business logic is handled using java/spring.In such cases can we use angular for improving interactivity/UX of web page.

Comment: If you want to shore up interactivity in a Spring application, you can do that a number of ways without involving Angular.  Angular *replaces* what Spring already does on the server, so unless you [use Spring to make JSON or XML web services](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/) that Angular consumes, it doesn't make much sense to have both.